# Passing class objects as arguments in Windows 8 App and receive them on click event

Tags: windows-8, c++-cx

The objects passed as arguments are only received an Navigation event. I want to receive them on Click Event,what should I use instead of Parameter??

```
void App1::MainPage::btuN_Click(Platform::Object^ sender,     Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
Variables^ data = (Variables^)e->OriginalSource;
if (data->sNotf!=nullptr)
    Frame->Navigate(TypeName(BlankPage3::typeid), data);
}
```

I used OriginalSource, but it didn't work. Would any one help me? Thanks in Adv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`OriginalSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.routedeventargs.originalsource.aspx) property contains a reference to the object that raised the event. It has nothing to do with navigation parameters.

I'm not exactly sure which parameters you'd like to access in your button click event. The ones passed to your page in its navigation event? In this case you should handle said navigation event, retrieve the parameters there and store them into a private field of your page. In click event you can then read them back from the private field and pass them forward.

On a related note: passing non-basic types as navigation parameters is [discouraged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702394.aspx). If you need to do that, it's a better idea to just pass the object ids and read their values inside the page from a common repository.

Comment: The page, on which I passed object and receive on OnNavigatedTo event, is to be accessed by another page as well. So it gives an error whenever I navigate from a page from which I am not interested to pass an object.

Comment: @WaqasAhmedAnsari So, you're navigating to the same target page from two different pages, once with a parameter passed in and once without it? In this case just check in `OnNavigatedTo` if `e->Parameter` is `null` and don't attempt to read it in this case

Comment: I am very new here, so confused. And one thing please, how can I not receive it as it was already read by the code
Variables^ data = (Variables^)e->Parameter;???? Do I check 
If(data->sNotf==nullptr)
like this? And If I do so, then what would be the next line?
Very big thank to you, Sir!

Comment: @WaqasAhmedAnsari I'm not sure which part is confusing you. You said, you wanted to open the same page from two different places - once with the parameter and once without it. By checking in `OnNavigatedTo` you can detect how the page was loaded and react accordingly. Andy has given you a sample how to store the parameter in page for future use from e.g. `Click` event. One more thing: when you open the page from the location witout the parameter a new instance of the page is created - the parameter that might have been passed before to that page isn't available in it.

Comment: I don't know why, I am a bit confused! When I navigate from a page-from which I don't want to pass an object-it checks whether an object is passed or not. If it assure that no objects is passed-i.e. null object is passed-so what will I do next?

Comment: @WaqasAhmedAnsari That's up to you. From your scenario I understand that you have two ways of accessing the page: (a) with a parameter which somehow affects the behavior of the page, and (b) without it causing the page to behave in some default manner. In case (b) you just have to make sure you never access the object you didn't pass. You could e.g. provide some kind of default value and use that.

Answer (score 1):

When you navigate to your page, if the parameters from your navigation event are important, you should store them within your page object so it can be accessed later.

```
//MainPage needs to have a private Variables^ named Info
void MainPage::OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs^ e)
{
  if(e->Parameter)
    this->Info = dynamic_cast<Variables^>(e->Parameter);
}
```

And then access that variable from within your click handler:

```
void MainPage::btuN_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
  if(this->Info)
    if (this->Info->sNotf!=nullptr)
      Frame->Navigate(TypeName(BlankPage3::typeid), Info);
}
```